# Troubles with UTF-8 in emails (SMTP) after form has submitted

Tags: php, forms, post, utf-8, smtp

I recieve mails with CP1252 while need UTF-8 because of cyrylics.

My php code:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$to = '...@mail.com';
$from = '...@mail.com';
$subject = 'SUBJECT';
$body='par1:   '.$_POST['par1'].'Message:  '.$_POST['message'];

$SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
$SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
}

...

<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

I also have

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
```

I have tried many options but anyway have mails in CP1252. 
How to find right solution for this trouble?

Comment: You seem use a not default class. It is your own class or 3rd part class (like [this](https://github.com/renebigot/SMTPClient/blob/master/SMTPClient.php), i.e.)?

Comment: Right. Its 3rd part  class. It works well. I just have troubles with encoding.